# DBAccess creating custom DBAccessSettings

Tags: ios, dbaccess

I am testing DBAccess in order to see if I can use it in a project. I have problems changing the location of the sqlite file, I want it to be in cache directory. Here is part of the code I wrote until now, in AppDelegate.m :

```
- (DBAccessSettings*)getCustomSettings {
    DBAccessSettings *settings = [[DBAccessSettings alloc] init];
    NSURL *applicationCachesDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    settings.databaseLocation = [applicationCachesDirectory absoluteString];
    settings.defaultDatabaseName = @"myDefaultDB";
    return settings;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [DBAccess setDelegate:self];
    [DBAccess openDatabaseNamed:@"NSURLProtocolExample"];    
    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyURLProtocol class]];
    return YES;
}
```

But with the above code I get the following error message:

**error >> unable to open database file**

Can you shed some light in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DBAccess, but you have these lines:

```
NSURL *applicationCachesDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
settings.databaseLocation = [applicationCachesDirectory absoluteString];
```

That will retrieve a URL string (one that starts with `file://`), not a file path. If you want the path of that folder, you want to use `path`:

```
settings.databaseLocation = [applicationCachesDirectory path];
```

Frankly, [the documentation](http://docs.db-access.org/interface_d_b_access_settings.html#ac8bff478fd39fc2fb0d33d7220d6b82c) is ambiguous as to whether its expecting a URL string or a path, but I would assume it expecting the latter.

Comment: Thank you Rob for pointing out the floor in the documentation, I have amended the comment to be more specific (along with lots of the other parts of it) and this will be included in the next build/release